# Pythonic way of counting max elements by index in a dictionary with list values

Tags: python

I want to compare the lists inside a dictionary (as values) by each index, and save in another dictionary how many times each "key" had the highest value.

Let's put an example, I have this dictionary:

```
my_dict = {'a': [1, 2, 5], 'b': [2, 1, 4], 'c': [1, 0, 3]}
```

I want to end up with a dictionary like this:

```
count_dict = {'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'c': 0}
```

Because:

- at index 0 of the lists we have:
  `1` from 'a' ; `2` from 'b' ; and `1` from 'c'.

  So 'b' has the highest value for this index and adds one to the count.
- at index 1 of the lists we have:
  `2` from 'a' ; `1` from 'b' ; and `0` from 'c'.

  So 'a' has the highest value for this index and adds one to the count.
- at index 2 of the lists we have:
  `5` from 'a' ; `4` from 'b' ; and `3` from 'c'.

  So 'a' has the highest value for this index and adds one to the count.

---

I've tried with `Counter` and `max(my_dict, key=my_dict.get)`. But what would be the most pythonic way instead of doing this:

```
for i in range(len(my_dict['a'])):
    max_value = max(my_dict[key][i] for key in my_dict)
    for key in my_dict:
        if my_dict[key][i] == max_value:
            max_count[key] += 1

print(max_count)
```

Comment: I don't think I understand what's the goal here...

Comment: @alex Basically, I want to compare by the same index within all the arrays, which one has had the highest value and append this to a new dictionary where I count how many times each key was choosen.

Comment: https://realpython.com/python-counter/ python counter contains what you are looking for.

Comment: If you want the highest value - why in the output `b` key has value 1, the highest value at index 1 is 2 from value for key `a` in the input dict. Or why `c` value is 0. If you want the index of the array - then why `a` has value 2. And note that up to and incl. python 3.6. dict is unordered

Comment: And what if max value is present in more than one list?

Comment: becaues that's the result @buran. if you compare the arrays by index, how many times each value has the highest value.

Comment: Then pick whatever,  but that's not gonna happen with my numbers. @buran Good point by the way

Comment: @buran He means to look at a single index of each array at the same time, then see which of the keys holds the highest value for that index. So for index 0 of the arrays, `b` holds the highest value(2). Now do it for every index of the arrays(assuming they're all the same length) and get the result he stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can zip them:

```
res = {k:0 for k in my_dict}
keys = [*my_dict] # note that order in dictionaries is only guaranteed in python 3.7+
for l in zip(*my_dict.values()):
   res[keys[l.index(max(l))]] += 1
```

Comment: That's 2x more efficient. I like that

Comment: @ToninoFernandez This might be even more efficient by removing the `index` call and instead doing `max(enumerate(l), key=lambda x: x[1])` this will return a tuple with the max value ***and its index***. So it can be changed to `res[keys[max(enumerate(l), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]]] += 1`

Comment: Also, to avoid being dependent on the dicts orders (only from Python 3.7) you can just do `keys, values = zip(*my_dict.items())`

Answer (score 1):

You can [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the [`values`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) after manipulating them to contain their respective key:

```py
zip(*([(k, v) for v in l] for k, l in my_dict.items()))
# gives: [(('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 1)), (('a', 2), ('b', 1), ('c', 0)), (('a', 5), ('b', 4), ('c', 3))]
```

and now for each item, find the [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) according to the *value*, and increment the count of the matching *key*:

```py
from collections import Counter

my_dict = {'a': [1, 2, 5], 'b': [2, 1, 4], 'c': [1, 0, 3]}

c = Counter()
for item in zip(*([(k, v) for v in l] for k, l in my_dict.items())):
    c[max(item, key=lambda x: x[1])[0]] += 1

print(c)
```

Will print `{'a': 2, 'b': 1}` since `c` was never added. But the beauty with [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)s is that even if you do `c['c']` you will still get `0`.

---

This doesn't rely on the keys' order or index and so will work for any Python version.

Answer (score -1):

An alternative approach using `zip()` together with enumerate and lambda.

```py
dict_result = {key: 0 for key in my_dict}

for idx, values in enumerate(zip(*my_dict.values())):
    max_key = max(my_dict, key=lambda k: my_dict[k][idx])
    dict_result[max_key] += 1
    
print(dict_result)
```

---

```
{'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'c': 0}
```